# How can I set my navbar as well as the list items inside it smaller?

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/x5vt8L2j/

How do I make the elements inside my inverse navbar as well as the navbar itself be a smaller height?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div >

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-left" id="ulSpacing">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Live</span> Podcast</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kolumnisti</a></li>
      <li><form class="navbar-form " action="/action_page.php">
      <div >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchBar">
      </div>

    </form>
    </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Cannot find .mr-left in your CSS styles, can you add it (please)?

Answer (score 0):

You may find it difficult to shrink the height of your inverse navbar. One of your elements includes the search form and browsers generally include a `<br>` before and after the `<form></form>` tags. Let's compare your values line by line.

---

HTML:
`<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">` calls two CSS styles which indicate a height of somewhere between 20-30px.

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    height: 30px;  }

.navbar-inverse {
    min-height: 20px; }
```

---

HTML: There are references to `.mr-left` and `#ulSpacing` with no related styles in your CSS. Review your code to see if they have any values indicated that would affect your inverse navbar.

```
<div >

<ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-left" id="ulSpacing">
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;  }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>ul>li>a {
    width: 100%;  }

.mr-left {   MISSING CLASS STYLE   }

#ulSpacing {  MISSING ID STYLE  }
```

---

HTML: Skip down to the `<li><form...` Both the `.navbar-form` and the `#searchBar` have extra spacing around the element. Try adjusting that by a few pixels.

```
  <li><form class="navbar-form " action="/action_page.php">
  <div >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchBar">
  </div>

</form>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-form {
    margin:5px 30px 3px 5px;  }

#searchBar {
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    height: 90%  }
```

---

Also note:  the misplaced closing tag:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: white;

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
    background-color: white;
}

}
```

---

Ok, those are the thing that I noticed which would have an effect on your inverse navbar. Take a moment to consider how each layer of the nesting elements affect the overall design, then make the adjustments you deem needed. Hope this helps.